# Ajax parameter not getting passed if not manipulated

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, handler

So I'm getting this weird bug that maybe I'm missing out on something,

I have this js script:

```
function openStationLoadWindow(inStationString) {

theStationString = inStationString;
$.ajax( { 
    url : "Ajax.faces?popup=true",
    type : "GET",
    cache : false,
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data : {
        action : "retrieveStnLoadWindow",
        selectedStations : theStationString
    },
```

and at the ajax handler I'm trying to get selected stations:

```
String theStationString = itsContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getParameter( "selectedStations" );
```

theStationString is empty. However when i append a string at the js portion:

```
function openStationLoadWindow(inStationString) {

**theStationString = inStationString + "ANY";**
$.ajax( { 
    url : "Ajax.faces?popup=true",
    type : "GET",
    cache : false,
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data : {
        action : "retrieveStnLoadWindow",
        selectedStations : theStationString
    },
```

---

```
String theStationString = itsContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getParameter( "selectedStations" );
```

I am able to get theStationString + "ANY".

Any ideas?

Comment: Look in developer tools to see what req. params are really getting sent with the request.

Comment: hi. i recently checked this and it turns out the parameter name being passed is `selectedStations%5B%5D`. consequently, i need to use `.getParameter( "selectedStations[]" );` any ideas why and how to fix?

Comment: Hi guys upon further inspection, we get the "string" from a multiple select box. The cause might be that js is considering it as a list and not a string. Hope it helps for who might be having the same problems.